# expected specifier-qualifier-list in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error

When I tried to compile the below code I get the above error mentioned, I don't know the cause of it and how to rectify it.Please explain me what is my mistake and suggest me a way to rectify it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *f1,*f2;
    int i,j,k;
    int n;
    char a,b,c;
    printf("Enter the number of students whose details you wish to enter:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    typedef struct //structure definition
    {
        char *che;
        che=(char*)malloc(5*sizeof(char)); //1st error.
        char *c;
        c=(char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
        int rollno;
        int branch;
        float gpa;
        switch (branch)
        {
        case 1:
             {
                che={'E','C','E'};
                break();
             }
        case 2:
             {
                che={'E','E','E'};
                break();
             }
        case 3:
             {
                che={'C','S','E'};
                break();
             }
        case 4:
             {
                che={'C','E'};
                break();
             }
        default :
             {
                printf("WRONG INPUT\n***********");
             }                  
        }

    }stud;
    stud *details;
    details=(stud *)malloc(n*sizeof(stud));
    printf("Enter the details of the students as prompted:\n1:ECE \n2:EEE               \n3:CSE \n4:CE(Chemical ENginering)");
    f1=fopen("details.txt","w");
    if (f1 == NULL)      
    {          
        printf("I couldn't open the file\n");          
        goto cha;   
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the name of the number %d student\n",n);
        fscanf(f1,"%[^\n]s",&details[i].c);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nEnter the rollno. of the number %d student\n",n);
        fscanf(f1,"%d",&details[i].rollno);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nEnter the branch code of the number %d student\n",n);
        fscanf(f1,"%d",&details[i].branch);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nEnter the gpa of the number %d student\n",n);
        fscanf(f1,"%f",&details[i].gpa);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    fclose(f1);
    f2=fopen("details.txt","r");
    printf("\nThe details you entered are:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nThe name of the number %d student \n",n);
        fprintf(f1,"%s",details[i].c);
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("The rollno. of the number %d student\n",n);
        fprintf(f1,"%d",details[i].rollno);
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("The branch code of the number %d student\n",n);
        fprintf(f1,"%d",details[i].branch);
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("The gpa of the number %d student\n",n);
        fprintf(f1,"%f",details[i].gpa);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    fclose(f2);
    cha :;  
}
```

Errors:
16  3   C:\Users\rkbsh_000\Desktop\Untitled10.c [Error] expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'che'.

I also get the error "does not name a type ".Please explain me about this error too.

Comment: You can't have statements or expressions in structure definitions, only declarations.

Comment: So can I do the memory allocation outside the structure

Comment: Having `malloc()` calls and `switch` statements in a `struct` definition is wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot;But how can I dynamically allocate memory for the variables in structure.Sorry I'm new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know that che is a type.Include the appropriate header file.

OR

As you know,The compiler parses the file from top to bottom.Make sure a type is defined BEFORE using it into another.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it

Comment: Try giving hardcoded values.
Like,
che=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);